# How to get the current map from a geoprocessing tool execute function?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, geoprocessing, java, arcgis-10.2

I'm making a geoprocessing tool with the ArcObjects SDK Java 10.2. I need to modify labeling colors of a layer of the current map.
Is it possible from the execute function to access the map currently opened in ArcMap ?
I need to get the current IMapDocument or IMap in order to set up parameters of the layers (IGeoFeatureLayer).
How can I do that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getMap()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geoprocessing/GPUtilities.html#getMap%28%29) or [getMapLayers()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geoprocessing/GPUtilities.html#getMapLayers%28%29) methods of the [GPUtilities](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geoprocessing/GPUtilities.html) class. Note that this can return `null` depending on how and where your geoprocessing tool is run.

If you need to specify rendering of an output layer, I believe the correct way to do that is to implement [IGPFunction2.getRenderer()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geoprocessing/IGPFunction.html#getRenderer%28com.esri.arcgis.geoprocessing.IGPParameter%29) method on your GP function class.

Comment: Yes, as my geoprocessing tool extends a BaseGeoprocessingTool, I can access a gpUtilities object and then get the activeView or map if the gp tool is launched in an ArcMap environnement. Thanks a lot for this help !

Answer (score -1):

.Net function to return the current active IMap, not sure if you can adapt this for java... good luck!

```
Public Function GetMapFromArcMap(ByVal application As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IApplication) As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap

  Dim mxDocument As ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument = CType(application.Document, ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument) ' Explicit Cast
  Dim activeView As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView = mxDocument.ActiveView
  Dim map As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap = activeView.FocusMap

  Return map

End Function
```